# Visual Force Flows

Tags: visual-flows

Hi I have a doubt on VF flows. I am supposed to make a survey where in there is a question that needs to be answered using a flow. However the task is that once a user selects an option for eg: good, a value of 5 should be recorded. Any help with that using flows?